# SwiftUI's List is behaving strangely

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I want to implement an expandable list, but I need to be able to represent rows with different shapes. So I implemented it using the `Item` protocol, as shown in the code below.

```
struct RowItem: Identifiable {
    let item: Item
    let children: [RowItem]?
    
    var id: Int {
        item.id
    }
}

protocol Item {
    var id: Int { get }
}
```

then, I defined an example of a real data model as follows.

```
struct PrimaryRowItem: Item {
    let firstProperty: String
    let secondProperty: String
    let index: Int
    
    let secondaries: [SecondaryItem]
    
    var id: Int {
        return index
    }
    
    static let mockedData: [PrimaryRowItem] = [
        PrimaryRowItem(firstProperty: "PrimaryFirst_1", secondProperty: "PrimarySecond_1", index: 1, secondaries: SecondaryItem.mockedData),
        PrimaryRowItem(firstProperty: "PrimaryFirst_1", secondProperty: "PrimarySecond_2", index: 2, secondaries: SecondaryItem.mockedData),
        PrimaryRowItem(firstProperty: "PrimaryFirst_1", secondProperty: "PrimarySecond_2", index: 3, secondaries: SecondaryItem.mockedData)
    ]
}

struct SecondaryItem: Item {
    let firstProperty: String
    let index: Int
    
    var id: Int {
        return index
    }
    
    static let mockedData: [SecondaryItem] = [
        SecondaryItem(firstProperty: "SecondaryFirsrt_1", index: 1),
        SecondaryItem(firstProperty: "SecondaryFirsrt_1", index: 2),
        SecondaryItem(firstProperty: "SecondaryFirsrt_1", index: 3),
        SecondaryItem(firstProperty: "SecondaryFirsrt_1", index: 4)
    ]
}
```

Finally, I draw a List based on the above model.

```
struct TestList: View {
    
    var models: [RowItem] = PrimaryRowItem.mockedData.map {
        RowItem(item: $0, children: $0.secondaries.map{ RowItem(item: $0, children: nil) })
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        List(models, children: \.children) { model in
            if let primaryRow = model.item as? PrimaryRowItem {
                VStack {
                    Text(primaryRow.firstProperty)
                        .font(.system(size: 17))
                    Text(primaryRow.secondProperty)
                        .font(.system(size: 12))
                }
                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            }
            else if let secondaryRow = model.item as? SecondaryItem {
                Text(secondaryRow.firstProperty)
                    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.plain)
    }
}
```

I have attached the behavior below.

[here is behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddX2X.gif)

In addition to this strange behavior, the `.listRowSeparator(.hidden)` method is also not working.

I am curious about why the method is not working, and why it is behaving strangely.

Is there another way to implement Expandable List?

---

Here is My Environment

- deplyment target: iOS 16.0
- Swift version: Swift 5
- Xcode varsion: 14.3.1

I want the list to expand and collapse with a correct animation.

Comment: You have more than 4 secondary items, but they only have 4 unique IDs. You should not have duplicate IDs.

Comment: I have tried to assign `UUID()` to `id` as the answer below, but it does not work.

Comment: Well I never said *that* was why the code didn't work :) I don't know the answer, but having unique IDs is a thing you should do.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing

```swift
var id: Int {
   return index
}
```

to

```swift
let id = UUID()
```

inside all `struct` that has id?

---

Update: I tried your code, it works perfectly with or without above changes. [Video](https://imgur.com/a/fiwDz9Y)

Comment: Thank you for your response.
But it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, I'll try your code and debug then update my answer. Wait a sec.

Comment: @Eddy it seems your code is already working. I've ran on iOS 16.31 iPhone 12 with Xcode 14.3 Added video link to the answer. Maybe I should delete the answer since it doesn't affect.

Comment: It seems to be a bug that occurs on iOS 16.4 or later.